# How to open multiple instance of the same Tinymce editor?

Tags: javascript, java, html, javafx, tinymce-5

I have a situation where the first instance of `Tinymce 5` is in small window, I would like to open the same instance in a Fullscreen dialog or a popup in the way that when I edit the content and close it, the content be synchronize.
I use java fx webview.

It means that:

1. `redo` and `undo` function should be aware of changes.
2. The content should stay synchronized.

**Any genus one any idea how to open the same instance of `Tinymce` multiple times?**

What I have done and what I know:

1. I have created two different instance and used `getContent` and `setContent` to synchronize them but `redo and undo` of first instance is not aware of changes.
2. I am aware of following Tinymce API but didn't help me much.
   [Multiple editor instances sharing the same configuration](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/multiple-editors/#multipleeditorinstancessharingthesameconfiguration)

Comment: So that someone familiar with [tag:tinymce] might be able to see what you see, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows a simplified version of your current approach.

Comment: See also [_How to integrate Tinymce into JavaFx webview?_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70904995/230513)